# Querying multiple text files to merge the columns and show output using Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two text files which contains the data as shown below and I want to display the output in the format described in Python. I am using PyCharm IDE with Python 3.0. I also tried using the dictionary and list in Python but I was not able to get it correctly.

[File1.txt]

```
2|Stacey|Tucker
4|Simi|Mirza
9|Naved|Singh
6|Ram|Patel
7|Joe|Pruth
```

[File2.txt]

```
2|26
6|17
9|30
4|31
7|35
```

print output desired:

```
2  Tucker,Stacey   26
4   Mirza,Simi      31
9   Singh,Naved     30
6   Patel,Ram       17
7   Pruth,Joe       35
```

Can anybody give me a suggestion?

Comment: What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck?

Comment: You haven't shown any effort - post your code! Read the two PSV files, merge/join on the id column, then print them out. pandas package is strongly recommended for this. There are countless questions on SO telling you how to those.

Comment: Are you open to using a 3rd party library (e.g. `pandas`) or looking to learn the ropes from first principles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the files aren't huge you can read each one, appending the rows into a list(one for each file). Then split the rows on '|'.  This will give you index[0] to match on.  So then you can take the pieces of each list and merge into a new list to output.
The new list would have [0] from either list, [2] from file1list + "," + [1] from filelist1 + [1] from filelist2.

```
#merglist.py

student_id = [] 
grade = []

file1 = open("file1.txt")
file2 = open("file2.txt")

f1 = file1.readlines()
for line in f1:
    student_id.append(line.split('|'))

f2 = file2.readlines()
for line in f2:
    grade.append(line.split('|'))

for g in grade:
    for s in student_id:
        if g[0]==s[0]:
            newline = g[0] + " " + s[2].strip("\n") + ", " + s[1] + " "+ g[1].strip("\n")
            print newline

| => python2 mergelists.py 
2 Tucker, Stacey 26
6 Patel, Ram 17
9 Singh, Naved 30
4 Mirza, Simi 31
7 Pruth, Joe 35
```

Comment: e = file.readlines()
id = []
grade = []
for i in e:
id.append(i.split("|")[0])
grade.append(i.split("|")[1].strip("\n"))
file = open("D:\PyProjects\\class.txt","r")
f = file.readlines()
cid = []
fn = []
ln = []
for i in f:
cid.append(i.split("|")[0])
fn.append(i.split("|")[1])
print(cid[0]+'\t'+ln[2]+','+fn[1]+'\t'+grade[1])

Comment: i just did but this gives only the data at specified index